# ManageIQ all files return 404 Not found

Tags: ruby, docker, manageiq

I cloned the repo https://github.com/ManageIQ/manageiq/ and used the `Dockerfile` to build the docker image. But when I start the container none of the files are served.

It seems the files required are under `public/` directory but I'm not sure where it should be copied manually. I tried copying all files to `app/assets/` but still I get the same error.

Any idea where the `public/*` files should be copied to?

This is how the default login page looks like

[image]

And there's a lot of errors on the console.

[image]

`config/application.rb` says the following and I've tried that already as stated above.

```
# TODO: Move to asset pipeline enabled by moving assets from public to app/assets
config.asset_path = "%s"
```

Answer (score 0):

The monolithic docker image is not built directly from source as is normally expected from a Dockerfile. Instead, it is built on top of the podified (kubernetes) image for the UI worker, with some bootstrapping on top ([ref](https://github.com/ManageIQ/manageiq/blob/9b78eb89d762e91bf751c4760218ec0b3e42897e/Dockerfile)). The podified images use RPMs that are built nightly from the various source repositories, which includes packing the UI code that is found in /public/packs.

If the image build is failing then either there is something wrong with the UI worker image or some services are not starting. You best bet is to open an issue at https://github.com/ManageIQ/manageiq/issues .